# UnicodeDecodeError - Error while reading the file

Tags: python, unicode

I am getting a UnicodeDecodeError when reading a file that has non-ascii characters. Here is the snippet of code

```
import codecs
import locale

print locale.getpreferredencoding()

fname = "c:\\testing\nonascii.txt"
f=codecs.open(fname,"r",encoding='utf-8')
sfile=f.read()


print type(file) #it's unicode


print sfile.encode('utf-8')


print type(sfile.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: give us the first few lines of `nonascii.txt`.

Comment: Also give us the error, and where you are getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the filename, you're using Windows. Files on Windows will *not* be UTF-8 encoded unless you take special care to save them that way; by default they will use your [code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page).

If you don't know what code page Windows is using, you can use the special encoding `mbcs` to get what it uses for a default. If you want your program to work on other systems besides Windows, you can use `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` to get a value that should work on the current system; on Windows it will return `mbcs`.

```
import sys
f=codecs.open(fname,"r",encoding=sys.getfilesystemencoding())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file is not really UTF-8.

One possiblity is that it is [UTF-16 with a Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16). If this is the problem, your error will be one of:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 0: invalid start byte
```

or

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

depending on the endianess of the file.

There are other possible encodings that might be in use. If you post the actual traceback we might be able to tell more definitively.